# React table not repopulating after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my React page I have a DataTable component, the source of which is a `data` array in my state. In my `useEffect` I call an action to get the data, map through it and define an object for each row, push it to a new array and do `setData` to that new array.

It works fine on initial load, but if I click refresh the table is blank and the code doesn't run again

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listContractors())
        const newData = new Array;

        contractors.map(c => {
            let obj = {
                action: `DELETE | EDIT`,
                psa_licence_no: c.psa_licence_no,
                company: c.company,
                trading_as: c.trading_as,
                address_1: c.address_1,
                address_2: c.address_2,
                address_3: c.address_3,
                county: c.county,
                eircode: c.eircode,
                contact_f_name: c.contact_f_name,
                contact_s_name: c.contact_s_name,
                office_tel_no: c.office_tel_no,
                mobile_tel_no: c.mobile_tel_no,
                sentinel_id: c.sentinel_id,
                email: c.email,
                intruder: c.intruder,
                cctv: c.cctv,
                guard_static: c.guard_static,
                arc_intruder: c.arc_intruder,
                arc_cctv: c.arc_cctv,
                issue_date: c.issue_date,
                expiry_date: c.expiry_date,
                psa_date_added: c.psa_date_added,
                psa_date_updated: c.psa_date_updated,
                psa_date_removed: c.psa_date_removed
            }
            newData.push(obj)
        })
        setData(newData)
    }, [dispatch])
```

EDIT:

If I refresh the page from the app, so navigate to a different page and navigate back to this one, it works. The problem only occurs if I click the refresh button on chrome

Comment: Do you have some form of server-side rendering? also, where does the contractors variable come from?

Comment: Also, you're using `.map` as if it's `.forEach`. If you use `.map` on an array, you don't have to create a new array (`newData`) and push to it. You can return values from the callback. I.e. `newData = contractors.map( c => { return {…} });`

Comment: @Marco `contractors` is coming from redux,

 `const contractorList = useSelector(state => state.contractorList)   
const { loading, error, contractors } = contractorList`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `contractors` in dependency array in `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listContractors())
        const newData = new Array;

        contractors.map(c => {
            let obj = {
                action: `DELETE | EDIT`,
                psa_licence_no: c.psa_licence_no,
                company: c.company,
                trading_as: c.trading_as,
                address_1: c.address_1,
                address_2: c.address_2,
                address_3: c.address_3,
                county: c.county,
                eircode: c.eircode,
                contact_f_name: c.contact_f_name,
                contact_s_name: c.contact_s_name,
                office_tel_no: c.office_tel_no,
                mobile_tel_no: c.mobile_tel_no,
                sentinel_id: c.sentinel_id,
                email: c.email,
                intruder: c.intruder,
                cctv: c.cctv,
                guard_static: c.guard_static,
                arc_intruder: c.arc_intruder,
                arc_cctv: c.arc_cctv,
                issue_date: c.issue_date,
                expiry_date: c.expiry_date,
                psa_date_added: c.psa_date_added,
                psa_date_updated: c.psa_date_updated,
                psa_date_removed: c.psa_date_removed
            }
            newData.push(obj)
        })
        setData(newData)
    }, [dispatch, contractors])
```

I recommend using eslint to catch this type of bugs.

Comment: Yeah, plus one on using eslint for this (with the [react-hooks plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks), naturally )

Comment: This is something I tried but now I get a fatal error "Cannot read property "map" of undefined"

Comment: That must me something wrong with your redux state management then :)

Comment: @MichałPokojski I don't think so as if I look in my redux dev tools, there is still an array full of objects